# Reading a spellbook costing all my money

Tags: nethack

After reading a "dog eared spellbook" in Nethack 3.6.0, all my money is lost. I've made some search on the Wiki, but nothing relevant can be found.

So what's that evil spellbook? Is this a new feature added since Nethack 3.6.0?

[image]

Comment: That doesn't sound like a very effective hack...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this feature exists in 3.4.3 as well. Upon [failing to read a spellbook](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Spellbook#Failure_effects_of_spellbook_reading), one of the possible effects is

> 4. All your (visible) gold vanishes: "You notice you have no gold!" ("money" in 3.6.0) (or "You feel a strange sensation.", if you had no gold).

Other possible effects include [paralysis](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Paralysis) (always occurs, even with [free action](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Ring_of_free_action)), random [teleportation](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Teleportation), [blindness](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Blindness) or [confusion](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Confusion), [strength](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Attribute#Strength) and/or [HP](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Hit_points) loss, and so on. The spellbook itself is also sometimes destroyed.

This is why you should never read an unidentified spellbook ([unless you are a wizard](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Spellbook#Success_rate_for_spellbook_reading), in which case you will be warned before reading too-difficult spellbooks). Always [price-ID](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Price_identification) spellbooks before reading them.

As a general rule of thumb, your [experience level](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Experience_level) should be around 4-5 times the level of the spellbook you're trying to read, assuming an [Intelligence](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Attribute#Intelligence) of ~15. When in doubt, [check the formula for success rate](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Spellbook#Success_rate_for_spellbook_reading) on the wiki.

Comment: Sometimes I would read an expensive spellbook in a store on purpose, so that I may escape from(in case of teleportation) that store with all unpaid items.

Comment: Also note that a blessed spellbook is always safe to read (as mentioned in the wiki), no matter the level of the book, intelligence or experience level.

Answer (score 0):

The spellbook could be anything. Your experience level is too low to read it.

Comment: Any evidence to support this?